# How do I use ternary operator within className?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css

```
<button className= {checked == false ? "w-32 h-32 rounded-2xl bg-white-200"
      : "w-32 h-32 rounded-2xl bg-orange"}

      onClick={() => {
        setClicked(!checked)
      }}>
```

I'm using tailwind, react.
I tried to change the code like above to the code below.

```
className=`w-32 h-32 rounded-2xl ${!checked ? 'bg-white-200' : 'bg-orange'}`
```

However, a grammatical error occurred, and as I corrected it a little, I felt that the error was not solved more than I thought..
How do I modify it to implement what I want?

Comment: You should keep brackets `{}` to wrap it `className={\`w-32 h-32 rounded-2xl ${!checked ? 'bg-white-200' : 'bg-orange'}\`}`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

`` className={`w-32 h-32 rounded-2xl ${!checked ? 'bg-white-200' : 'bg-orange'}`} ``